# My js function not adding perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, html

As you can see there is a value already on the (total)textbox which i filtered on a table...and if i type a number on the (score)textboxes it will automatically add on the current value of the total(textbox).

My problem is its not adding perfectly.can anyone help me please.

example:

[image]

html code:

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(empty($name[0])){$name[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 1: <br />
<input type="text" name="optA" value="" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 2: <br />
<input type="text" name="optB" value="" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 3: <br />
<input type="text" name="optC" value="" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 4: <br />
<input type="text" name="optD" value="" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Total: <br />
<input type="text" name="totals" value="<?php if(empty($total[0])){$total[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[0];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
</form>
```

total calculation script:

```
<script>
function optTotal() {
        var a1 = document.forms[0].optA;
        var b1 = document.forms[0].optB;
        var c1 = document.forms[0].optC;
        var d1 = document.forms[0].optD;
        var xtotal = document.forms[0].totals;
        if (a1.value && a1.value != "")
            a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
        else
            a1 = 0;

        if (b1.value && b1.value != "")
            b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
        else
            b1 = 0;

        if (c1.value && c1.value != "")
            c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
        else
            c1 = 0;

        if (d1.value && d1.value != "")
            d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
        else
            d1 = 0;
        if (xtotal.value && xtotal.value != "")
            xtotal = parseFloat(xtotal.value);
        else
            xtotal = 0;

        var total = a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + xtotal;
        document.forms[0].totals.value = total;

      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not storing the original value anywhere.

When you run your code again, you grab the *current* value from the total (the one you've already added 2 to) and then you add 5 to it again, so of course the value is now 15 (10 + 5).

You need to either get the original value on load and store it so that you are always adding to the original total, or else, get the old value from which ever text box has changed and *subtract* it from the total before you add the new value.

Personally, I think the first approach is probably easier.

So something like this on load:

```
 var xtotal = 0;    // define this somewhere so you can access it later in a closure or a global

 var xtotalElement = document.forms[0].totals;
 if (xtotalElement.value && xtotalElement.value != "")
     xtotal = parseFloat(xtotalElement.value);
```

Now in your `optTotal`:

```
function optTotal() {
    // get all the text boxes *except* the total as before
    // ...

    var total = a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + xtotal;     // this should be the original xtotal set on load
    document.forms[0].totals.value = total;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJ54y/)